# Azure + EF 6 - Making code first migrations work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 (code first with migrations) for MVC 5 project. On my local DEV machine everything works fine.

But when I deploy my project to Azure, I get the following error when my app first tries to interact with the database:

```
Migrations is enabled for context 'UtilitiesContext' but the database does not exist or
contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for
example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.
```

I have my EF related code in Utilities.Data assembly and my MVC project is in Utilities.Web assembly.

Here is my code for your reference:

**UtilitiesContext.cs**

```
public sealed partial class UtilitiesContext : DbContext
{
    public UtilitiesContext() : base(Settings.Get(Settings.DB_CONNECTION_STRING)) { }

    public DbSet<PreLaunchSubscriber> PreLaunchSubscribers { get; set; }

    private void SetCreatedAtUpdatedAt()
    {
        foreach (DbEntityEntry entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entityEntry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    ((IEntity) entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    ((IEntity) entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    [HandleException]
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SetCreatedAtUpdatedAt();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    [HandleException]
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        SetCreatedAtUpdatedAt();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<UtilitiesContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "Utilities.Data.Contexts.UtilitiesContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(UtilitiesContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

**Settings.cs**

```
public static class Settings
{
    public const string DB_CONNECTION_STRING = "DB.ConnectionString";
    
    // other settings ...

    public static string Get([Required] string key)
    {
        return CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key);
    }
}
```

And I have this defined in the `App Settings` section for the `Configuration` tab:

> Key: DB.ConnectionString
>
> Value: Data Source=tcp:host.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Utilities;User Id=user@server;Password=pwd;

Comment: did you add `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UtilitiesContext>(){}` in global.asax?

Comment: @Eddy4v No I have not. Do I need to? It's not there and it still works in my DEV image.

Comment: even so of you have to update your database throw package manager console using update-database
and make sure that your connection string name as same as your Context name witch is **UtilitiesContext**

Comment: Just a hint, if you are using migrations, you do not want to use `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UtilitiesContext>(){}` but `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MY_CONTEXT, MY_MIGRATION_CONFIGURATION>())`. Try to put it on a static constructor of your DbContext class (or on the global.asax). I have the exact same scenario as you and this works perfectly.

Comment: @Eiaddar I really don't like the idea of dropping database and re-creating it every time there is a change in Model. And that is why I have enabled migrations, dropping database defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem you are experiencing is that you deployed your application to Azure, but the database it is trying to target doesn't exist yet.

The best solution for production code is to run the following command from the package manager console on your local machine, this will generate a sql script that you can run against your production database to bring it up to date with your application.

```
PM> Update-Database -script -sourceMigration 0
```

Alternatively if you just want to test in azure the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer will do what you need and make sure that your database is up to date whenever your app is started.  The use of initializers generally is not recommended for production code because altering your production database is something that should be done very carefully.

[This blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) is a little old but does a good job outlining both initializers and migrations.

Comment: What if the target database is EMPTY?  When I publish to Azure, it only updates the mdf in the App_Data folder (but Azure doesn't allow SQL Express) and the config connection string is overridden correctly with the SQL instance.  But that database remains empty.  And I can't figure out how to make a creation script for the database (or a migration from empty) using ef6 and these update-database tools.  PITA!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the DB set up in Azure and it contains some of your model but not yet your last changes, then while publishing to Azure, check "Execute Code First Migration (run on application start)" in the "Settings" section of the publish wizard.

Note: If you are browsing directly to a page which uses your changed model, and a error is thrown, then access a page of your application, that is using a part of your model that has not been changed since you last published!

This procedure works for me with EF 6.0.2 and VS 2013